# File extensions automatically recognized by writeRaster and rast for writing/reading raster files?

Tags: format, driver, raster, gdal, terra

How could I get the list of file extensions automatically recognized by writeRaster and rast functions, for writing and reading different raster file formats?

Comment: `gdalinfo --formats`

Answer (score 0):

You can see the extensions used for determining the file format for writing at line 50 of [this file](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/blob/master/src/write_gdal.cpp). This should eventually make it to the documentation.

Reading is not based on the extension. With the development version you can get a list of the supported formats like this:

```
d <- gdal(drivers=TRUE)
head(d)
#    name   type   can                     long.name
#1 AAIGrid raster write           Arc/Info ASCII Grid
#2    ACE2 raster  read                          ACE2
#3    ADRG raster write ARC Digitized Raster Graphics
#4     AIG raster  read          Arc/Info Binary Grid
#5  AirSAR raster  read     AirSAR Polarimetric Image
#6     ARG raster write     Azavea Raster Grid format
```